# ASP.NET MVC: Where can I get sample MVC Projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, model-view-controller

I am trying to implement authentication using ActionFilterAttribute in MVC and i am looking for some sample mvc project which has done this kind of authentication?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/aspnet/samples/aspnet-mvc

Comment: here's a demo: http://prodinner.aspnetawesome.com/account/SignIn, it uses Microsoft.Owin and related packages for Auth, older versions used FormsAuthentication, you can download current and older versions on http://prodinner.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try the MVC samples page, they have examples of authentication that should be what you are after.

http://www.asp.net/aspnet/samples/aspnet-mvc

Or there's the classic Nerd Dinner

http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm

Answer (score 0):

There's not really much to the action filter itself, the specific authentication will depend on your requirements which you've not detailed:

```
/// <summary>
/// Custom authorization attribute for use on controllers and actions. 
/// Throws an exception if the user is not authorized.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class ActionPermissionAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // Override OnAuthorization, not AuthorizeCore as AuthorizeCore will force user login prompt rather than inform the user of the issue.

        var controller = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
        var action = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
        var user = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity;

        // Check user can use the app or the specific controller/action
        var authorised = ...

        if (!authorised)
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("You are not authorised to perform this action.");

        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```